# Как использовать фильтры в данных случаях?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть контроллер регистрации пользователей:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    unless current_user
      @user = User.new
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are already signed up!"
    end
  end

  def create
    unless current_user
      @user = User.new(user_params)

      if @user.save
        sign_user_in(@user.auth_token)
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Signed up&in!"
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are already signed up!"
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Также есть контроллер входа пользователей на сайт:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    if current_user
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are already signed in!"
    end
  end

  def create
    unless current_user
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        sign_user_in(user.auth_token)
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have been succussfully signed in!"
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Wrong E-mail or password"
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are already signed in!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have been successfully logged out!"
  end
end
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы уже вошедший пользователь не мог попасть на страницы регистрации и входа (ибо зачем авторизованному пользователю заходить/регистрироваться на сайте еще раз?).
Сразу подумал использовать before_action, но дело в том, что у меня  метод current_user возвращает экземпляр класса User. Думал создать метод current_user?, который бы возвращал, вошел пользователь на сайт или нет (boolean значение), но тогда все равно придется использовать if(unless)/else конструкции. А это совсем не DRY. Как грамотно решить ситуацию, чтобы убрать дубликацию кода?

Comment: Вы используйте Devise? Он по-моему по умолчанию так и поступает, не дает зайти на страницу регистрации и входа, если вы уже авторизованы. У вас как роуты для него выглядят?

Comment: @cheops нет, не использую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом в отношении `UsersController`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :redirect_sign_in, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      sign_user_in(@user.auth_token)
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Signed up&in!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def redirect_sign_in
    if current_user
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are already signed in!"
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

И для `SessionsController`

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :redirect_sign_in, only: [:new, :create]

  def new; end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      sign_user_in(user.auth_token)
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have been succussfully signed in!"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Wrong E-mail or password"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have been successfully logged out!"
  end

  private

  def redirect_sign_in
    if current_user
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are already signed in!"
    end
  end
end
```

Чтобы определение метода `redirect_sign_in` не повторялось из контроллера в контролер его можно вынести в консерн, подмешиваемый в контроллеры при помощи `include`. Для этого в папке controllers заведите подпапку concerns, создайте в ней файл filters_concern.rb следующего содержания

```
module FiltersConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def redirect_sign_in
    if current_user
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are already signed in!"
    end
  end
end
```

После этого метод `redirect_sign_in` можно удалить из контроллеров и включить в них консерн `FiltersConcern`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include FiltersConcern

  before_action :redirect_sign_in, only: [:new, :create]
  ...
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include FiltersConcern

  before_action :redirect_sign_in, only: [:new, :create]
  ...
end
```

Comment: К сожалению, консерны мне не знакомы. Можно вынести в ApplicationController?

Comment: @МатвейМамонов так [ознакомьтесь](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html). Пригодится.

Comment: @МатвейМамонов, поправил ответ.

Comment: @D-side Само собой, если я узнаю,что с чем-то не знаком, то иду и читаю про это :) Но спасибо за ссылку, вы ускорили процесс.

Comment: @cheops Хорошо, спасибо, теперь понятно стало. Но все-таки: почему вы не вынесли этот метод в ApplicationController? Это плохая практика (выносить фильтры в ApplicationController)?

Comment: @МатвейМамонов, нормальная практика. Но не стал выносить, по той причине, что вам скорее всего метод redirect_sign_in больше нигде кроме этих двух контроллеров не пригодится. Если вынесем в ApplicationController метод будет у всех контроллеров (нужен они им или нет), а с консернами, только в тех, куда вы включите консерн. Мне кажется так более элегантно и правильно.

Comment: @cheops практика покажет, где надо, а где нет, я думаю. К некоторым страницам наверняка тоже надо будет ограничить доступ неавторизованным пользователям. Но спасибо, что дали понять про возможность использовать концерны. Если будет подобная ситуация, но с явно ограниченными условиями, то обязательно воспользуюсь.